# Webpack config to consume an API with no CORS header

Tags: reactjs, api, webpack, cors

I need to consume a public API with no CORS header in it. I'm very new in webpack so i take this approach by readind articles. The scaffolding is provided by the company. This is a second part from a exercise for a job.

I been looking for hours and nothing seems to help. I always get the same response `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ...`

This is my `webpack.config.js` at the moment

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})
module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      { test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    port: 1184,
    proxy: {
      'https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements': {
        target: 'https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx' ]
  }
};
```

my dependecies are:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.8",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2"
  }
```

and this is my jsx file which is a simple component to render an advertisement

```
import React from 'react';

import House from './index.jsx';

const publicApi = "https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements";

export default class Dinamic extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            advertisements: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        fetch(publicApi)
        .then((results) => {
                console.info('results: ', results);
                return results.blob();
            })
            .then ((data) => {
                console.info('data: ', data);
                const advertisements = data.results.map((ad) => {
                    return (
                        <div key="ads.results" >
                            <p>{ad.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                });
                this.setState({ advertisements });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("boom!: ", err);
            })
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Dinamic</h1>
          <div className="row">
                        {this.state.advertisements}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Did i miss something important or this is completely wrong?

Disclaimer: The job is for Web UI developer, but i think this is also fun to learn

Comment: try no cors. `fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' })` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: That gaves me an opaque response, not useful

Answer (score 2):

The browsers don't allow reading forbidden headers like 'set-cookie' from response and browser also does not allow setting 'Cookie' header. So I resolved this issue by reading cookie in onProxyRes method and saving it in a variable and setting the saved cookie on following request in onProxyReq method.

```
let cookie;
devConfig.devServer = {  
  proxy: {
    '*': {
      target: https://target.com,
      secure: false, 
      changeOrigin: true, 
      onProxyReq: (proxyReq) => {
        proxyReq.setHeader('Cookie', cookie);
      },
      onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
        Object.keys(proxyRes.headers).forEach((key) => {
          if (key === 'set-cookie' && proxyRes.headers[key]) {
            const cookieTokens = split(proxyRes.headers[key], ',');
            cookie = cookieTokens.filter(element => element.includes('JSESSIONID')).join('');
          }
        });
      },
    },
  },
}
```